# Getting B+ matrix (Warshall algorithm) in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matrix, matlab

Pseudocode:

> ```
> // B = nxn binary matrix
> // Bm = resulting matrix
> for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
> {
>   for (j=1; j<=n; j++)
>   {
>     if (B[i,j] == 1)
>     {
>       for (k=1; k<=n; k++)
>       {
>         Bm[i,j] = B[i,j] | B[k,j];
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

This is the Warshall algorithm written (in my way):

```
B = [1 1 0 0 0; 0 0 0 1 0; 0 0 0 0 1; 0 1 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0];

n = 5;

Bm = zeros(n);

for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:n
        if B(i,j) == 1
            for k = 1:n
                Bm(i,k) = B(i,k) | B(k,j);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

It works but, how can I improve the matrix loops?

Comment: Did you mean `Bm(i,j) = B(i,k) | B(k,j)`?

Answer (score 2):

This post may help you in removing a loop:
http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=845980

Furthermore, one way to speed up your code is to use a short circuit logical operator:

```
B(i,k) || B(k,j);
```

Also it seems to have a small effect if you use a logical matrix as input rather than a double:

```
B = logical(b);
```

Last and least, it would be nicer to initialize Bm with the datatype that it will have:

```
Bm = false(n)
```